# Transaction mails from my website goes as spam

Tags: php, magento, email, phpmailer, spam

In magento, I have set my website store email address as example@mydomainname.com

For this email id, I use Google mail service.
When my website sends any mail to customers, email goes in spam folder.

Kindly tell me why email goes as spam. what is the solution?

host I use: localhost ,
port: 25 , 
I have a valid email address with my domain name.

Comment: What E-Mail Service ist it that puts your E-Mail to the SPAM Folder?

Comment: I think you should set a valid emailid in store email address.

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses the MX record and unauthenticated email services to send email.

Most SMTP servers consider mail from these sources to be spam nowdays.

Get Ashley Shroeder's secure SMTP module and set it up so you have to log into an email account that sends email using SSL/TLS encryption. Then set up SPF records showing the authorized servers that are supposed to be the email sources for your domain.